# Laravel: set password page automatically redirects to login after 1 second

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on an app where I can register a user and send him an email to set a password. After clicking on the button in the email to redirect the user to the Set Password page, the page opens up for one second and automatically redirects to the login page. I'm not sure which files are involved in this but here are the ones I think are important to understand the error. Please, let me know if I should provide additional code. Thank you!

Routes api.php:

```
Route::post('single-use-links/resend-email', [SingleUseLinkController::class, 'resendEmail'])
    ->name('resend-single-use-link-email');
```

Routes web.php

```
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function ($router) {
    Route::get('/users/{user}/single-use-link/{token}', [SingleUseLinkController::class, 'view'])
        ->name('single-use-link');
    Route::post('/users/{user}/single-use-link/{token}', [SingleUseLinkController::class, 'consume'])
        ->name('single-use-link-consume');
});
```

ResetPasswordController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showResetForm($token, Request $request)
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            [
                'token' => $token,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'pageTitle' => 'Password Reset | Prospect Path',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

SingleUseLinkController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\SingleUseLinks\SingleUseLinkManager;
use App\SingleUseLinks\SingleUseLinkType;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager as Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\View\Factory as View;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class SingleUseLinkController extends Controller
{
    protected $auth;

    protected $redirector;

    protected $linkManager;

    protected $view;

    public function __construct(
        Auth $auth,
        Redirector $redirector,
        SingleUseLinkManager $linkManager,
        View $view
    ) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->redirector = $redirector;
        $this->linkManager = $linkManager;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function view(User $user, string $token)
    {
        // Throw 404 if the link isn't valid
        if (! $this->linkManager->check($user, $token)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        // If the link type is Product, consume the link straight away and redirect to the team sign up page
        // otherwise go to the set password page
        $linkType = $this->linkManager->getLinkType($user, $token);
        if ($linkType->reference === SingleUseLinkType::TYPE_PRODUCT_USER_INVITE) {
            $success = $this->linkManager->consume(
                $user,
                $token
            );

            // Throw 404 if the link isn't valid
            if (! $success) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException();
            }

            $this->auth->login($user);

            if ($user->teams()->count() === 0) {
                return $this->redirector->to('/signup/teams');
            } else {
                return $this->redirector->to('home');
            }
        }

        return $this->view->make('app.users.single-use-link', [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token,
            'pageTitle' => 'Set a Password | Prospect Path',
        ]);
    }

    public function consume(User $user, string $token, Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|max:255|confirmed',
        ]);

        $success = $this->linkManager->consume(
            $user,
            $token,
            $request->get('password')
        );

        // Throw 404 if the link isn't valid
        if (! $success) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        $this->auth->login($user);

        $linkType = $this->linkManager->getLinkType($user, $token);

        // If the invite type is product user and they have no teams redirect to the team signup
        if ($linkType->reference === SingleUseLinkType::TYPE_PRODUCT_USER_INVITE &&
            $user->teams()->count() === 0
        ) {
            return $this->redirector->to('/signup/teams');
        }

        return $this->redirector->route('home')
            ->with('success', 'Your password has been set');
    }
}
```

ValidateRouteParametersRelations:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Exceptions\InvalidRouteParameterException;
use App\Team;
use App\Teams\BelongsToManyTeams;
use App\Teams\Repos\Teams;
use App\Traits\HasParentObjectInterface;
use App\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager as Auth;

/**
 * Find any route parameters which have the HasParentObject trait
 * and validate that the correct parent object is present.
 *
 * If the currently authenticated user is a super admin users and teams will be
 * checked first against the super admin then against any route parameters.
 * For non super admins the currently authenticated users and their team will be
 * used to validate objects with a user or team as a parent.
 */
class ValidateRouteParameterRelations
{
    public function __construct(
        Auth $auth
    ) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $parameters = $request->route()->parameters();

        if ($this->isIgnoredRoute($request)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        foreach ($parameters as $name => $parameter) {
            // If the parameter class has the HasParentObject
            // trait confirm parameter
            if ($parameter instanceof HasParentObjectInterface) {
                $this->confirmParameter($parameter, $parameters);
            }

            if ($parameter instanceof BelongsToManyTeams) {
                $this->confirmBelongsToTeam($parameter, $parameters);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function isIgnoredRoute($request) : bool
    {
        $tokens = $request->route()
            ->getCompiled()
            ->getTokens();

        return collect($tokens)
            ->filter(function ($token) {
                return $token[0] === 'text';
            })
            ->pluck(1)
            ->contains('/single-use-link');
    }

    protected function confirmParameter($parameter, array $parameters)
    {
        $name = $parameter->getParentObjectName();

        if (is_null($name)) {
            throw new InvalidRouteParameterException(
                'getParentObjectName configured incorrectly on'.get_class($parameter)
            );
        }

        // If the user is a super admin only validate if there is a parent
        // parameter in the route.
        if ($this->auth->user()->isSuperAdmin()
            && ! array_key_exists($name, $parameters)
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $parentObject = $this->getParentObject($parameter, $parameters);

        if (! $parameter->checkAgainstParentObject($parentObject)) {
            throw new InvalidRouteParameterException();
        }
    }

    protected function getParentObject($parameter, array $parameters)
    {
        $class = $parameter->getParentObjectClass();
        $name = $parameter->getParentObjectName();

        // If the parent param is a user or team
        // and the parent parameter
        // isn't in the url use the currently authenticated user's values.
        if (in_array($class, [User::class, Team::class])) {
            $user = $this->auth->user();

            if (! array_key_exists($name, $parameters)) {
                switch ($class) {
                    case User::class:
                        return $user;
                    case Team::class:
                        return $user->team;
                }
            }
        }

        if (! array_key_exists($name, $parameters)) {
            throw new InvalidRouteParameterException();
        }

        return $parameters[$name];
    }

    protected function confirmBelongsToTeam(BelongsToManyTeams $belongsToManyTeams, $parameters)
    {
        $team = $parameters['team'] ?? null;

        if (null === $team) {
            return;
        }

        if (
            $belongsToManyTeams->teams->reject(function (Team $existing) use ($team) {
                return ! $existing->is($team);
            })->count() === 0
        ) {
            throw new InvalidRouteParameterException();
        }
    }
}
```

After checking if the blade.php template and the controller were causing this issue to happen, I tried to create a public function to ignore certain routes on the file ValidateRouteParameterRelations in Middleware but that also didn't solve the issue.

```
 protected function isIgnoredRoute($request) : bool
{
    $tokens = $request->route()
        ->getCompiled()
        ->getTokens();

    $ignoredRoutes = [
        '/single-use-link',
        'single-use-link-consume',
    ];

    return collect($tokens)
        ->filter(function ($token) {
            return $token[0] === 'text';
        })
        ->pluck(1)
        ->contains(function ($path) use ($ignoredRoutes) {
            return in_array($path, $ignoredRoutes);
        });
}
```

Comment: I would have expected a redirect somewhere but the odd part is that you can see the set password page before being redirected. Are you sure there is no client-side javascript that would redirect you ?

Comment: You are redirecting the user I think , when calling maybe the consume in the view method , that automatically failed to authenticate a user and it redirect to home or Something else then that page isn't for guest, please `dd` in each step to catch the redirecting error